# Apples and Oranges

Tags: logical-deduction

You were on a grocery shopping day, you go to the store, and your friend tells you he'd like you to pick him up some fruit, naturally you try and be a kind friend and agrees to pick it up for him, you ask him what he wants and he replies:

"Alright, I need some apples and oranges, I'd like 3 of each, but if there's only 2 apples I want 5 oranges, but if there's only 4 oranges, pick up 3 oranges and 1 apple. Otherwise if there's only 2 oranges, I want 1 orange and 6 apples, but if there's only 5 apples, give me 4 apples without any oranges. Understood?"

So you go grocery shopping and there's 3 apples, the store just got stocked up with plenty of oranges, so oranges aren't a problem, what do you do?

Comment: I think this shouldn't be tagged "Logic-Puzzle". More along the lines of "Trick Question", perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on availability of oranges... you get 3 oranges and those 3 apples. He requested 3 of each.